# Sorting files with Google Drive API

Tags: sorting, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Is there a workaround to sort the files while uploading them? I need a specific filter for the files besides the 4 standard ones in Google Drive. I thought about inserting a dummy modifiedDate as the files will not be available to be edited and sorting it by a specific date name i specify while uploading the files.

All files that need the sorting will be uploaded so I could actually access and write the metadata as the script wishes. I've seen that the feature has been requested but I haven't found a viable answer or the feature actually being implemented so I'd appreciate any help or ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I read this Q twice and I still don't understand what it is you're trying to do. You say "sorting" and then you say "filter". How about a link to the feature request?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language, there might be some things lost in translation. I need a special order for the items to appear, besides the 4 ones that appear in Drive. I want them to appear in this order in the Drive interface, as I could easily do it if it was in another view or webpage.

Comment: "I've seen that the feature has been requested" - can you provide a link to the request?

Comment: Let me search for the specific links, they popped up when I was searching for this stuff. Also it appears that it was implemented in previous versions of the API but was removed.